# Remove top margin of a TextView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

I've got some `LinearLayout` objects with several things in them, including two `TextView`s. Unfortunately, I've got a huge space between them and I don't know why.

See by yourself (between the content frame and the `#642954 - 14/25/9814` thing):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/832QN.png

Here is my code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:contentDescription="@string/smiley"
        android:padding="10dp"
        />

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:includeFontPadding="false"
        >

        <TextView android:id="@+id/contenu"
             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
             android:layout_height="fill_parent"
             android:background="@drawable/round"
             android:padding="10dp"
             android:layout_margin="5dp"
             android:includeFontPadding="false"
             android:layout_marginBottom="-10dp"
             />


        <TextView android:id="@+id/infos"
             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
             android:layout_height="fill_parent"
             android:gravity="right"
             android:layout_margin="5dp"
             android:includeFontPadding="false"
             android:padding="0dp"
             android:layout_marginTop="-10dp"
             />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Here is `round.xml`:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <solid android:color="#20000000" />

            <corners android:radius="13dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:bottom="2px">
        <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
            <solid android:color="#FFFFFF" />

            <corners android:radius="13dp" />

            <stroke
                android:width="1dp"
                android:color="#BBBBBB" />
        </shape>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

Could you help me?

Thanks!

Comment: bertal's answer should definitely be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, no, no. You use negative margins, which may have unspecified behavior (presumably depending on Android OS version). I've tested this on API 8, and negative margins simply don't work. Instead, set each and every margin to a custom non-negative value, like so:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:contentDescription="@string/smiley"
        android:padding="10dp"
        />

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:includeFontPadding="false"
        >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/contenu"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/round"
            android:includeFontPadding="false"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/infos"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:includeFontPadding="false"
            android:padding="0dp"
            android:text="" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Here, I've set all margins to `5dp` except for:

- `contenu`'s bottom margin: `0dp`
- `infos`' top margin: `0dp`

And voila, all the space is gone. Set them to your liking to adjust the gap between first and second `TextView`.

**Edit**

I've checked SDK sources for *unspecified behavior* I was writing above.

It turns out that when specifying margins for `LinearLayout` children, you have two options one of which must you choose:

1. Set `margin` property. This effectively sets *all* side margins to the value of `margin`. **Beware:** This option has precedence, meaning, if you set non-negative value for `margin` it will ignore any values which you have individually set for any side margins.
2. Set every side margin individually.

You were setting global `margin` value which effectively caused the `marginTop`/`marginBottom` values to be ignored.

Comment: Thanks, it works ! I put negative margin to try removing the space, and I forgot to remove it after. Anyway, there is still a little space, how could I remove it totally ?

Comment: I've tested it and there is no space between `contenu` and `infos`. Maybe you want to set less padding for `contenu`, eg. `padding="5dp"` instead of `padding="10dp"`? If not, please post a screenshot with the space marked.

Comment: If I set less padding for contenu it's ugly plus it doesn't work x) Here is an image (with a 10dp padding) : http://up2sha.re/uploads/LsORtQegomZK.png

Comment: I've just tested my code in Nexus 7 and there is *no gap* (it is `0`). So I guess that you have something other that is causing the space, for example the `infos.text` start with a newline character or there's something in your layout that you didn't include in the sample code here.

Comment: Am so stupid, I put a <br /> somehere and I don't remeber why but it was the problem. Thanks !

Comment: @user1947177 glad you finally resolved that :) Also please remember that SO is about helping others, so accept an answer which you find most valuable. That helps others coming here in choosing a right one.

Comment: Yep, no problem I did it (i'm new so i can't vote up but i accepted it). Thanks again !

Answer (score 6):

android:includeFontPadding="false"

Answer (score 1):

try this for equal spacing

```
   <TextView android:id="@+id/contenu"
             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
             android:layout_height="fill_parent"
             android:background="@drawable/round"
             android:padding="10dp"
             android:layout_margin="5dp"
             android:includeFontPadding="false"
             android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
             />


        <TextView android:id="@+id/infos"
             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
             android:layout_height="fill_parent"
             android:gravity="right"
             android:layout_margin="5dp"
             android:includeFontPadding="false"
             android:padding="0dp"
             android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
             />
```